# Pipeline threw a ContactLockException. Processing the task will be retried later

Tags: exm

In my system I have 200+ automated emails which needs to be triggered to all registered user (based on condition) overnight. However, few emails are not getting send and getting stuck. I have manually resumed it couple of times, but the issue is getting bigger every time. Now I can see almost 20 emails are getting stuck on daily basis. When I check log I can see an exception as -

```
1924 13:50:07 WARN  One or more tasks processed by task agent 'sent_message_task_pool' failed. The agent will revert to the slowest processing speed possible.
3296 13:50:08 INFO  Failed to process task. Pipeline threw a ContactLockException. Processing the task will be retried later. Contact id: 531eb87c-901e-42d6-9f2f-eade880aaf91, message id: {3767F0C5-5999-432F-8C78-CB9C8EA8770F}
4860 13:50:39 ERROR Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The operation has timed out
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.DedicatedDispatch.SitecoreDedicatedDispatchService.Status(String messageID)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Services.DedicatedServers.Status(MessageItem message, Int32& totalNumServers)

5616 13:50:39 ERROR Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The operation has timed out
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.DedicatedDispatch.SitecoreDedicatedDispatchService.Status(String messageID)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Services.DedicatedServers.Status(MessageItem message, Int32& totalNumServers)
```

This exception message getting triggered in every 2 minutes. When I manually resume them, they get processed successfully. So, I'm not quite sure. If anyone could help.